# JavaScript: Difference between toString and toString()

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm struggling to understand this JavaScript behaviour (javascript n00b alert!!!). Source of the question is a typo in my code which led to the undesired situation. What I wanted to know is the length of a certain number. For example, if its 100, then answer should be 3, if 5893 then answer should be 4 and so on. To achieve this what I did simply is convert number to a string and then invoke `.length` on the string.

```
private getNumberLength(num: number) {
    return num.toString().length;
}
```

In the above `return` statement, I had typo such that it looked like

`return num.toString.length;`

The result was no compilation error and `getNumberLength` always returned `1`. I fail to understand this (why `1`?). Can somebody please help me understand this?

Below you can quickly test if you wish

```js
var num = 666;

console.log('Length on toString(): ' + num.toString().length);
console.log('Length on toString: ' + num.toString.length);
```

Comment: `toString` is the function, whose `.length` is the number of formal parameters in its definition ... for a number, there is one such parameter - hence the length is 1 ... as opposed to `.toString()` which executes the function returning a String ... of course, I'm assuming the "typo" was `return num.toString.length;` based on the title of your question

Comment: @JaromandaX should that be an answer?

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks for the explanation and also updated the question to remove the typo. Guess am master of typos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is Javascript behavior of automatically boxing primitive values to its Object counterpart to call its method.

The function looks correct, but to answer your question (I don't understand the downvotes).

`toString` is a reference to the function. The reason why `toString.length` works is because as quoted from Mozilla.

> Function.length = The length property indicates the number of parameters expected by the function.

So if you redeclare your function as

```
private getNumberLength(num: number, num2: number) {
    return num.toString().length;
}
```

`getNumberLength.length` will return 2.
`toString.length` will return 1 as it only expects one parameter.

**Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length**

toString() is invoking the function toString (and getting its return value). This is performing the actual conversion to String.

All the best with Javascript

Comment: Thanks, Philip for a detailed answer and also the link to the documentation. And yes I also don't understand the downvotes but nevermind.

Comment: Downvotes are likely because the issue is a typo. Whether or not the reason is interesting.